# LaunchMode singleTask from android activity

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest

I added to a activity `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to escape a memory consumption problem (Explanation: that activity contained bitmaps & lets say i had that activity in the backstack, when i received intent with my broadcast & opened that activity -> i had 2 of the same activity consuming memory due to their bitmaps)

```
<activity android:name=".activity.XActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

but now i have other problem, that activity is the main activity, so each click on app icon restarts app (in the sense that without this attribute, click on app icon will bring to front the current activity of the app)

How can i escape this? I've also tried some combinations of flags when sending intent.. but not much success..

Comment: have a look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
          notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: Not a solution because the Launcher is launching his activity, not @pulancheck1988 himself.

Comment: so yeah i've tried: removed attribute from manifest & intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); .. i also need the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK else big error since im starting activity from broadcastreceiver .. & All this combination doesnt work in the sense that app crashed due to outOfMemory (that's why i added that android:launchMode="singleTask" .. to not have two instances of the same activity in memory)